# Add Title to Seaborn Cat plot - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, graph, seaborn

I want to set a title to my seaborn catplot, but when I try with this code:

```
ax = sns.catplot(x="AA", col="BB",data=df, kind="count",order= AA,
                  height=5, aspect=1.9)

ax.set_title("Title")
```

I get this error:

```
AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_title'
```

Comment: As per the Duplicate, try `ax.fig.suptitle('Title')`

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I wonder why the question didn't get close by your duplicate mark. Your reputation alone is sufficient to do that

Comment: @Bazingaa The ability to close a question as dupe is provided by the "gold badge" in any of the question's tags. I do have a python and a matplotlib gold badge, but this question did not contain these tags initially. I edited them in later.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest: I see.

Comment: g = sns.catplot...... then do g.ax.set_title("Title")